# Stucco alternative for a small section of a wall?

Tags: exterior, door-frame, stucco

I'm trying to remove this exterior door, and replace it with a window:

[image: the door]

The plan is to remove the door and frame, make top and bottom places from 2x3s, run 2x3s beams every 12" and make an opening for a window, adding extra 2x3s under the window to help with weight. The frame is about 30" by 72".

The only issue I'm concerned is stucco finishing at the outside. I read about it, and it seems to be quite time-consuming application requiring multiple steps, and three coats. Are there any alternatives to stucco masonry which would be suitable for the exterior and could provide necessary protection?

In particular, would something like that work?

- Regular plywood attached to studs;
- The moisture barrier (self-adhesive film or roofing felt) nailed;
- Pressure-treated plywood on top of it;
- Sprayed texture and exterior paint;

Would this be enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar with a stucco house I owned where I closed in a window opening to create a shower. I framed in the wall with and installed rough-sawn cedar plywood. The texture coordinated with the stucco nicely.

You don't want to install the plywood flush with the stucco. It'll look like a bad patch. You want it set back a bit like it's a design accent. Maybe 1-2".

Caulk the plywood to the stucco and then prime and paint. If it's not in a very wet location it'll last many years, after which you can overlay a new sheet if necessary.

Comment: Thank you! Would I need an ordinary CDX plywood, or shall I invest in pressure-treated or fire-resistant plywood? There is no contact with ground..

Comment: Cedar plywood should be exterior grade. CDX is something different, and not well suited to finish work. You'd want BC(X) or better for good appearance, but I'm not sure that grading scale applies to the cedar.